# An exercise from fundamentals of python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fundamentals of Python Chapter 8 project 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374300/fundamentals-of-python-chapter-8-project-3)

Hi I am a newbie programmer who just started to learn about python.
I have recently posted this same question before and I have solved it but my answer is not exactly what the question is asking.

I need help on why I need to implement a new method even though I could do the other way.

thanks

Question:

> The `__str__` method of the `Bank` class returns a string containing the
>   accounts in random order. Design and implement a change that causes
>   the accounts to be placed in the string by order of name. 
>   *[this is the part where I don't understand]*
>   ***(Hint: You will also have to define a new method in the SavingsAccount class.)***

```
class Bank(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._accounts = {}
    def __str__(self):
        """Return the string rep of the entire bank."""
        pTemp =[]
        for i in xrange(len(SavingsAccount.temp)-1):
            if self._accounts.get(SavingsAccount.temp[i]).getName() >= self._accounts.get(SavingsAccount.temp[i+1]).getName():
                temp = SavingsAccount.temp[i]
                SavingsAccount.temp[i] = SavingsAccount.temp[i+1]
                SavingsAccount.temp[i+1] = temp
        for i in SavingsAccount.temp:
            pTemp.append(self._accounts[i])
        return '\n'.join(map(str, pTemp))

    def add(self, account): 
        """Inserts an account using its PIN as a key."""
        self._accounts[account.getPin()] = account
    def remove(self, pin):
        return self._accounts.pop(pin, None)
    def get(self, pin):
        return self._accounts.get(pin, None)
    def computeInterest(self):
        """Computes interest for each account and 
        returns the total."""
        total = 0.0
        for account in self._accounts.values():
            total += account.computeInterest()
        return total

class SavingsAccount(object):
    """This class represents a Savings account
    with the owner's name, PIN, and balance."""
    RATE = 0.02
    temp = []
    def __init__(self, name, pin, balance = 0.0):
        self._name = name
        self._pin = pin
        self._balance = balance
        SavingsAccount.temp.append(self)
    def __str__(self):
        result =  'Name:    ' + self._name + '\n' 
        result += 'PIN:     ' + self._pin + '\n' 
        result += 'Balance: ' + str(self._balance)
        return result
    def getBalance(self):
        return self._balance
    def getName(self):
        return self._name
    def getPin(self):
        return self._pin
    def deposit(self, amount):
        """Deposits the given amount and returns the
        new balance."""
        self._balance += amount
        return self._balance
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        """Withdraws the given amount.
        Returns None if successful, or an
        error message if unsuccessful."""
        if amount < 0:
            return 'Amount must be >= 0'
        elif self._balance < amount:
            return 'Insufficient funds'
        else:
            self._balance -= amount
            return None
    def computeInterest(self):
        """Computes, deposits, and returns the interest."""
        interest = self._balance * SavingsAccount.RATE
        self.deposit(interest)


def main():
    bank = Bank()
    bank.add(SavingsAccount("Zelda","1003",5000.00))
    bank.add(SavingsAccount("Wilma","1001",4000.00))
    bank.add(SavingsAccount("Fred","1002",1000.00))
    print bank

main()
```

Comment: If the answer you got for your original question isn't the one you wanted then update the original question and explain why, please do not ask a duplicate question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question expects you to **define ordering** in the SavingsAccount class, that is, be able to determine whether an instance of `SavingAccounts` comes after or before another instance of `SavingAccount`. I don't want to write any spoiler here, but tell me if my hint is not enough ;).

**UPDATE**
Also, a common source of errors in Python with string ordering : `a` comes before `z` which comes before `A` which comes before `Z` ...

**UPDATE2**

more hints ;)

What you really want here is to sort a list of instances of SavingAccount according to a given criteria. There are 2 way to do this kind of thing. You can either :

1. have the one doing the sorting take care of it
2. or you can have the instances stored in your list taking care of it.

The second option is usually better because "the class to be sorted" should know better than anybody else how to sort itself (it's about encapsulation : not letting people outside control how your class works). Even though the question is not really clear, and the example is not very good (in my opinion), this is the option they would like you to chose.

The idea is that the Bank should just do something like this :

```
class Bank(object):

    def __str__(self):
        """Return the string rep of the entire bank."""
        #get a sorted copy of the list 
        #using default SavingAccount comparison            
        pTemp =sorted(self._accounts) 
        return '\n'.join(map(str, pTemp))
```

And `SavingAccount` contains information about how to sort.

You may want to have a look at [this article from the PythonInfo Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting).
Also: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__

Comment: if you can help just a bit that would be great though.

Comment: @tsimbalar: I don't get why they want a separate method in SavingsAccount either to be honest, just sort them before you create the string in __str__ :) But oh well, homeworks have their own point to them.

Comment: @tsimbalar I mean how do I access SavingsAccounts instance from Bank class?

Comment: @favoretti: I mean that is what I did here. But I am trying to understand another way of doing this?

Comment: @user1047092: your self.accounts() is a list of SavingsAccount classes. You access them from there. Or if you want to add a new one, just create new instance, same way you created it from you main program.

Comment: @favoretti: well. from what I understand, if I want to define a ordering method in SavingAccount class, I need to create an instance in Bank class. Since I have a list of instances like you said but each instance is different from each other therefore, it is unnecessary to define a method of ordering like tsimbalar suggested.

Comment: @tsimbalar Thanks for your additional hints!

Comment: Bit of a moderator "oops" here: @FrederikCreemers - can you re-add your comment - *"what i think you need to do is create a **cmp__method on the savingsaccount, which compares the account to another account. python will use that when you use certain sorting functions. –"*